# Cannot upload a file using autoit in selenium python IE 11

Tags: python, selenium, autoit

i'm having problem trying to upload in IE 11 with autoit

This is the python code that i used:

```
filePath = "file_to_upload.txt"
autoit.control_focus("Choose File to Upload","Edit1")
autoit.control_set_text("Choose File to Upload","","Edit1",filePath)
autoit.control_click("Choose File to Upload","","Button1")
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="fileUpload"]').send_keys(filePath)
```

when i run my python script, i got this issue:

File "C:\Users\gc54734\Desktop\Automation\Python\importar_ok_DFT.py", line 61, in 
    autoit.control_focus("Choose File to Upload","Edit1")
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\autoit\autoit.py", line 84, in wrapper
    raise AutoItError(err_msg)
autoit.autoit.AutoItError: Window/Control could not be found

i'm trying this too, without success (file upload windows is opened, but the file is no chosen):

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="fileUpload"]').send_keys(filePath)

autoit.win_activate("Choose File to Upload")
autoit.control_set_text("Choose File to Upload","","Edit1",filePath)
autoit.control_click("Choose File to Upload","","Button1")
```

Could you get me an extra hand with this?

Answer (score 1):

It has been 8 months, but I had similar problem. Solution is to add 5 second sleep between clicking on button and looking for open window.